# How to: Given a value (x,y,z) from an arry [U,x,y,z] output associated value of U

Tags: python, arrays, data-manipulation

This seems like it's simple but I'm looking for a very computationally efficient (fast) way to do this. I have a set of data organized as such as a N by 4 numpy array.

```
 data = [[U[0],x[0],y[0],z[0],
          U[1],x[1],y[1],z[1],
          ....
          U[N],x[N],y[N],z[N]]]
```

What I would like to do is write a function that will take the actual numeric values of some given combination of elements x[N],y[N],z[N] as input and output the numeric value of U[N] that is in that same row.
There is no analytic function describing the data, it is purely numeric and so all I need is to give some combination of physical positional values say (x[51],y[51],z[51]) that will output the value of U that is in the row that has x[51], y[51], z[51]. An example on how it should work is given below:
Say x[51] = 2.4, y[51] = 6.3, z[51] = 9.45 and U[51] = 13.665

```
 input >>  
 function(2.4,6.3,9.45)
 output >>
 13.665
```

So the goal is essentially for me to figure out how to write the function that would do this in an efficient way!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is not clear, at least to me. You say you have "a set of data"--what data structure are all the `[U,x,y,z]` organized in? That matters for your question, and it apparently cannot be a Python set. What exactly are `x2`, `y6`, and `z9`? Do you mean `x[2]` etc.? Are you saying that `U` is a tuple containing the values `U0`, `U1`, etc, or do you mean something else? What do you mean by `U_2,6,9`--do you mean `U(2, 6, 9)`? And so on. Please rewrite and clarify your question, using Python notation and data structures.

Comment: Could you clarify how do you get f(2.4,6.3,9.45)=13.665? What is the function behind it? If you do not provide the relation it is impossible to optimize or code an unknown

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question hopefully it is clearer now! Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is `data` very long, and do you expect the number of searches to be similar to the length of `data`, much more or much less? There are different algorithms for the various cases. e.g., if you will be doing a lot of searching, you could store the U values in a dictionary with (x[i], y[i], z[i]) as keys. That will take a little time to setup, but then give you instantaneous search results.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to do a lot of searching, you could store the `U` values in a dictionary and look them up with the `x`, `y` and `z` values, like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([
    [ 1.234, 3.7, 9.1, 2.74],
    [13.665, 2.4, 6.3, 9.45],
    [12.431, 8.1, 5.3, 4.25]
])
search_dict = dict(zip(map(tuple, data[:, 1:4]), data[:, 0]))
# or search_dict = {tuple(row[1:4]): row[0] for row in data}
search_dict[(2.4, 6.3, 9.45)]
# 13.665
```

Alternatively, this is a good job for pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['U', 'x', 'y', 'z']).set_index(['x', 'y', 'z'])
df.loc[(2.4, 6.3, 9.45), 'U']
```

Building the dictionary or DataFrame will take some time and memory, but then you will get very fast results for each search, regardless of the length of `data`.

If you have a big array and not many searches, you could use a brute-force search:

```
matched_rows = (data[:, 1:4]==np.array([2.4, 6.3, 9.45])).all(axis=1)
data[matched_rows, 0]
# array([13.665])
```

Comment: Will definitely give this a shot! Thank you!